# Display an iframe when hover certain content in a website

Tags: javascript

My team is developing a widget/sdk so people can embeed our code in their sites and display some useful things.

My question is:
once these owners embeed our code, is there a way for us to target certain content in their website?

We want to, for example, if the content in such sites include a hashtag with a word (say #stackoverflow), when the final user hovers that hashtag display an extra iframe on top of it, like a tooltip in the top of the word.

Is this doable?

We thought about creating a chrome extension so any the final user can have that functionality, but we're also wondering if that is doable when the 3rd party site embeeds our code too.

Thanks!

edit: just to clarify, the owner of the site has to embeed a .js file in their site to display our iframe.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask]. You need to provide some code to discuss. Your question is too broad as it is. We're not a discussion forum.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.